# Appropriate way to create event handler methods within classes?

Tags: java, oop, javafx

I have written a JavaFX program that has several Event Handlers in the 'start' method. These Event Handlers are responsible for switching the application scenes, and they work fine, but for reasons of organization I would like to have the code defined within the classes below the Application class.  The classes I have written for the program each correspond to a particular scene in the program, and I would like to move each of these Event Handler methods to be contained within the relevant scene. Doing so however requires the Stage object to be passed as a parameter to the class constructors, as the stage of the application is only visible within the start method.

Ideally what I would like to do is run the event listener methods in passing two objects that are both of the scene classes I defined. For example:

```
CredsForm credsForm = new CredsForm();

TicketForm ticketForm = new TicketForm();

ticketForm.runTicketFormHandler(ticketForm, credsForm);
```

For reference, one of the event handlers in my start method:

```
    //inputScene 'Enter' key event handler
    ticketForm.inputScene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler <KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle (KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (KeyCode.ENTER == keyEvent.getCode()){

                    //make request  
                    try {
                        ticketForm.makeInputRequest(credsForm.sessionCreds);
                     } catch (IOException ex){
                         System.out.println(ex);
                         credsForm.inputTitle.setText("Issue Encountered – Sorry!");
                         credsForm.inputSubtitle.setText("Your Zendesk Credentials May Be Invalid");
                         stage.setScene(credsForm.inputScene);
                     }

                    //status-line=bad, send user to credentials page - otherwise use confirmation page
                    if (!ticketForm.responseLine.equals("HTTP/1.1 201 Created")) {
                        credsForm.inputTitle.setText("Issue Encountered – Sorry!");
                        credsForm.inputSubtitle.setText("Your Zendesk Credentials May Be Invalid");
                        stage.setScene(credsForm.inputScene);
                    }
                    else {
                        stage.setScene(confirmPage.scene);
                   }
                }
            }
    });
```

The class I would like to hold this event handler under:

```
class TicketForm extends InputForm {

    //HTTP Request Data
    String responseLine;

    public TicketForm() {
        super();
        submit.setText("Submit");
    }

    public void makeInputRequest (String[] creds) throws IOException {

        //Setting Request Data

        //http request header fields
        String endpoint = "https://" + creds[0] +  "/api/v2/tickets.json";
        String contentTypeField = "application/json";
        String acceptField = "application/json";

        //variables for log date and time
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
        DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        String dateString = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        String timeString = timeFormat.format(cal.getTime());

        //json array (request body)      
        String subjectKeyValue = this.input_3.getText();
        String bodyKeyValue = "Ticket logged for "+ this.input_1.getText() 
                            + " with " + this.input_2.getText() + " at " + timeString + " on " + dateString;

        String jsonArray = "{\"ticket\": "
                            + "{\"subject\": \"" + subjectKeyValue + "\", " 
                            + "\"comment\": { \"body\": \"" + bodyKeyValue + "\","  
                            +                "\"public\":\"false\"}"
                            +"}";

        //Builing HTTP Client 

        //setting credentials provided in creds parameter
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(creds[0], -1),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(creds[1], creds[2]));

        //creating HTTP client object
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .build();

        try {
            //initiating POST request object with endpoint (defined above)
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(endpoint);

            //adding JSON object to POST request message 
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonArray));

            //adding header fields to POST request httpPost
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", contentTypeField);
            httpPost.addHeader("Accept", acceptField);

            //executing request and response processing
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpPost.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            try {
                //outputting response data
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                responseLine = response.getStatusLine().toString();

            } finally {
                response.close(); 
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you for the help. I was debating whether I should post this question under the programmer stack exchange or here, but please let me know if there's a better place to ask this type of question.

Comment: Assuming I understand your framework correctly, you can always get the stage in the `TicketForm` class with `Stage stage = (Stage) inputForm.getScene().getWindow();`. (As a note, I would probably prefer to replace the root of the scene, rather than the scene of the stage, which would be a considerable refactoring but would mean you just needed to retrieve the scene in your handlers, not the window.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions James, this helps a lot.

Comment: TBH, the "real" answer is probably to use a View-Model, which stores the state of the application, and then share the View-Model instance among all the controllers. If I have time later I'll elaborate on that...